# Furnace will not stay running

Tags: furnace

I have a Colman DGAA090BDTB, it won't run unless I cut the power for 10 seconds and turn it back on, then it will go to temp. and will not restart when temp. get low.
The furnace is 15yrs old

Comment: Please [edit] to tell us what trouble shooting you've done so far. After 15 years, it might just be time to replace the system...